# process.env.NODE_ENV is not working with webpack3

Tags: vue.js, webpack-3

I am trying to assign `NODE_ENV` to production using webpack3, and have tried the following code:

```
environment.plugins.append(
  'DefinePlugin',
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
  })
)
```

also tried:

```
environment.plugins.append(
  'DefinePlugin',
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('production')
    }
  })
)
```

In my component, I have the following:

```
document.myenv = process.env
console.log(`Running process.env.NODE_ENV: ${process.env.NODE_ENV}`)
```

If I inspect `document.myEnv` in the Chrome developer console, I see `NODE_ENV: production`.  However, the console.log statement shows `Running process.env.NODE_ENV: development` and Vue appears to be behaving in development mode.

How can I fix this so Vue runs in production mode?  If it makes a difference, we dynamically create `new Vue` in a few places.

Comment: Have you tried just setting `process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production'` without `DefinePlugin`?

Comment: @tony19 changing all `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm'` to `import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.min'` did the trick!  Please post as an answer and I will accept.